# time difference between import X and from X import Y

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I've noticed a small difference between execution times when I import math library and when I import just sqrt function from math library

I've created two samples to see the actual difference regarding time efficiency. My question is why there is a difference between these two approaches.

```
import math
import time
elapsed_time = 0
for j in range(0,20): 
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(0,1000000):
        math.sqrt(i)
    elapsed_time += time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time/20.0)
```

OUTPUT: 0.16759999752

```
from math import sqrt
import time
elapsed_time = 0
for j in range(0,20):
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(0,1000000):
        sqrt(i)
    elapsed_time += time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time/20.0)
```

OUTPUT: 0.137699997425

Comment: One possibility is that with the first example, your code has to search for the `math.sqrt` function in the code when the function starts. However, the second example already brings that function to hand *before* the timer starts, giving a slightly quicker result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of when you execute `import math` you are importing all functions classes or whatelse in math library than youre using more ram etc. but when you execute `from math import sqrt` youre importing just sqrt function in all math lib

Answer (score 0):

How often did you run your code? Run your code once has no statistical significance. The executing machines resources are not exclusivly for your code!

Comment: i've run the code for 10 times in a row, and the difference remains the same